# Saving the jmeter result .jtl files in the Slaves machine

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I have configured Jmeter distributed testing, and I'm successfully able to trigger the test from Master to Slave machine. But the results files are not being generated on Slave machine even if I explicitly added a Listener into the test plan.

Can anybody help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Question answered in [JMeter group](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/How-to-save-result-output-file-in-distributed-testing-td5719574.html) by @glinius:

> in `user.properties`, add: `mode=StrippedBatch`

> This will:
> remove some data from the SampleResults as the response body, but do you need response body during a High Load Test, NO, DEFINITELY NO !
> will send Sample Results as Batches and not for every sample reducing CPU, IO and network roundtrips

Answer (score 0):

Adding the listener itself is not sufficient, you need to specify the location for the .jtl file in the listener, i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) is a good choice

[image]

The user which is running the JMeter slave process must have write permissions to the folder specified. See [How to Save Response Data in JMeter article for more details if needed](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter). If you want to save the response data - make sure to provide `mode=Standard` property

Also make sure to provide the valid `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists` property, i.e. `APPEND` if you want to add new results to the existing file or `DELETE` if you want to overwrite the old results with the new ones.

The property can be passed via `-G` command-line argument from the master or via `-J` command-line argument from the slave. More information: [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Comment: Still the result not getting generated on Slave machine, did configured test plan as per the instruction given. I'm using Jmeter version 3.1 by the way.